# Symfony3でcookieにセキュア属性つけたい

Tags: php

Symfony1系やSymfony２系の記事は見つかるのですが、
Symfony３系で開発を行なっており、
タイトル通りcookieにセキュア属性をつけたいのですが設定方法がわかりません。
どのように設定すれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: 確かに見つかる記事は少ないですね。[公式ブログの記事(secure属性だけじゃなく一般的なSymfony3.3でのCookieの話)](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-cookie-improvements)、[Symfony3.4の公式ドキュメント](https://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Cookie.html#method___construct)なんかが見つかりました。`Cookie`クラスのコンストラクタで、`$domain`引数の次が`$secure`引数になっているので、それに`true`を指定すれば良いようですが。

Comment: 何かのymlで何か設定すれば自動でセキュア属性付与されるという認識で検索していたのですが、
教えてくださったリンク先のリファレンスを見て解決できました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

使い方がわかっていなかったのですが、
アドバイスありがとうございます。
以下のような感じで、newするときに「$secure」に「true」を設定しました。

```
$cookie   = new Cookie($key, $data, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly);
```